# Como reverter surroundContents de um texto selecionado?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou criando um editor rich text que terá as opções de tornar um texto selecionado em negrito, itálico, etc. Até o momento consegui envolver a seleção em uma tag `<span>`e criei uma classe CSS `bold`para deixar o texto negrito. Porém, não consigo removê-la, só está sendo adicionado vários elementos `<span class="bold">`vazias.

A minha função está desse modo:

```js
let div = document.querySelector("#text");
let btnBold = document.querySelector("#btnbold");

btnBold.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var selRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);

  if (selection != "") {

    let span = document.createElement("span");
    selRange.surroundContents(span);
    
    span.classList.toggle("bold");
  }
});
```

```html
 <style>
    .bold {
       font-weight: bold;
     }
 </style>

<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
  lorem ipsum content editable texto div
</div>
<input type="button" value="bold" id="btnbold">
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Comment: O elemento `<strong>` é utilizado em conteúdos que são de "grande importância", incluindo coisas de urgentes (como alertas).Tipicamente, estes elementos são renderizados por padrão, usando fontes em negrito. Contudo, ele não deve ser usado para simplesmente aplicar o estilo negrito; use o CSS `font-weight` para este propósito. Veja [elemento HTML <strong> Notas de uso](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong#notas_de_uso)

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu vi que realmente não é correto usar o strong apenas com intuito de deixar o texto em negrito. Porém, minha dúvida é se for usar o CSS `font-weight` como eu faria? Eu teria que ter uma tag envolvendo o texto selecionado para poder aplicar uma classe?

Comment: @DanielSantos sim, eu acho melhor que texto esteja envolopado em alguma tag, <div>, <p>, <span>, <h1> etc. Isso te dá mais controle não só no CSS mas no JS também do conteúdo....se a tag tiver um ID fica relativamente fácil adicionar ou remover classes dela

Comment: @adolfotcar sim, eu envelopei com a tag <span>. Porém, agora não consigo remover a classe "bold" que criei no css quando seleciono o texto que já está negrito. Ao invés disso, fica criando vários elementos <span> vazios com a classe "bold".

Comment: @DanielSantos, hoje estarei atarefado, ao final da tarde dou um feedback(a menos que a questão já esteja be, solucionada). Tudo bem, para você?

Comment: Daniel e @AugustoVasques, para remover o elemento criado pelo surround em um evento para "undo" poderia pegar o elemento ancestral com `Range.commonAncestorContainer`, mas creio que tem que verificar o `Range.startOffset` e `Range.endOffset` para evitar pegar elementos a mais (vou tentar elaborar algo, mas fica a sugestão)